# How do I access data from outside a function's scope?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm a new coder trying to learn the basics. For practice, I've built a little Node app that grabs the last tweet from a user's timeline and reverses it. Here's the code:

```
// REQUIRES
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
var Twitter = require('twitter');

// LOAD ENV VARIABLES
dotenv.load();

// MAKE A TWITTER CLIENT
var client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
  consumer_secret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
  access_token_key: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
  access_token_secret: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
});

// FUNCTION TO REVERSE A STRING
function reverse(s) {
  var o = '';
  for (var i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    o += s[i];
  return o;
}

// GRAB LAST TWEET FROM USER TIMELINE AND REVERSE IT
client.get('statuses/user_timeline', {screen_name: 'twitterapi', count: 1}, function(error, tweets, response) {
  if(error) throw error;
  // console.log(tweets);  // Last tweet object from timeline.
  var lastTweet = tweets[0].text; // Text from last tweet.
  var reverseTweet = reverse(lastTweet); // Last tweet reversed.
  console.log("\nYour last tweet was: " + lastTweet);
  console.log("\nYour last tweet reversed is: " + reverseTweet);
});
```

My question is: if I wanted to pass `lastTweet` or `reverseTweet` to another function outside the scope of that `client.get()` (for instance, to another text parsing function), how would I do that?

I've tried declaring the variables globally, but I think the async nature of the request/response screws it up. I'm definitely willing to learn about promises, callbacks, etc ( I understand zilch about them right now ) but I'm not sure if that's the right way to solve this particular problem.

Finally: if I'm not using the right vocabulary to ask the right questions, please let me know.

Comment: It would help to show the function you want to use `lastTweet` and/or `reverseTweet` in.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare the variable at a higher scope level:

```
// REQUIRES
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
var Twitter = require('twitter');
var lastTweet = null;
var reverseTweet = null;

// LOAD ENV VARIABLES
dotenv.load();

...
```

Or probably best way in light of the fact that the `client.get` is an asynchronous call, is to pass `lastTweet` or `reverseTweet` as arguments to another function and call that function in the callback of `client.get`. For example:

```
// REQUIRES
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
var Twitter = require('twitter');

// LOAD ENV VARIABLES
dotenv.load();

// MAKE A TWITTER CLIENT
var client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
  consumer_secret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
  access_token_key: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
  access_token_secret: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
});

// FUNCTION TO REVERSE A STRING
function reverse(s) {
  var o = '';
  for (var i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    o += s[i];
  return o;
}

// GRAB LAST TWEET FROM USER TIMELINE AND REVERSE IT
client.get('statuses/user_timeline', {screen_name: 'twitterapi', count: 1}, function(error, tweets, response) {
  if(error) throw error;
  // console.log(tweets);  // Last tweet object from timeline.
  var lastTweet = tweets[0].text; // Text from last tweet.
  var reverseTweet = reverse(lastTweet); // Last tweet reversed.
  console.log("\nYour last tweet was: " + lastTweet);
  console.log("\nYour last tweet reversed is: " + reverseTweet);

  anotherFunction(lastTweet, reverseTweet);
});

function anotherFunction(lastTweet, reverseTweet)
{
    // Do something with vars here
}
```

Comment: Ah, this one makes sense. I have what I _hope_ is a healthy reticence for declaring global variables unless absolutely necessary.

I'm going to gnaw on it for a while. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to declare reverseTweet or lastTweet outside of the client.get function.

You could do it as such:

```
// FUNCTION TO REVERSE A STRING
function reverse(s) {
  var o = '';
  for (var i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    o += s[i];
  return o;
}
var lastTweet = "";
var reverseTweet = "";

// GRAB LAST TWEET FROM USER TIMELINE AND REVERSE IT
client.get('statuses/user_timeline', {screen_name: 'twitterapi', count:     1}, function(error, tweets, response) {
  if(error) throw error;
  // console.log(tweets);  // Last tweet object from timeline.
  lastTweet = tweets[0].text; // Text from last tweet.
  reverseTweet = reverse(lastTweet); // Last tweet reversed.
  console.log("\nYour last tweet was: " + lastTweet);
  console.log("\nYour last tweet reversed is: " + reverseTweet);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I did try the global declaration `var lastTweet = ""` and so on, but kept getting empty variables, e.g., when I would `console.log(lastTweet)` outside/below the `client.get()` function, jt would just give me the empty string.

My early investigation here suggests that the problem is that the `console.log()` is outrunning the API res/req (race condition?). I _think_ promises are often used to solve these problems, but I was hoping there was some more explicitly functional way to do it, i.e., running discreet functions in a sequence and passing data between them.